# Is using largeheap in Android manifest a good practice?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am developing in `NDK`. It hangs in `Galaxy S3`. For testing I put `android:largeheap = "true"` in `Manifest`. Then there was no hanging issue. 
Is it a good practice to use `largeHeap="true"`?

Is there any chance that Google rejects my build due to this tag and
how can I prevent my app from hanging without using `largeheap="true"`?

Comment: If you app **actually** have some high memory requirements then you can but otherwise never a good practice.

Comment: Programmers should determine *why* they are hanging, rather than assuming that some random setting is a magic fix.

Comment: @charlotte can you mark my answer as answered if it has successfuly let you know what you were wondering?:)

Comment: Let me know if my answer is missing something! @charlotte

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### **Short Answer**

No, **if you need it** it is not a bad pactise because it is there for it.

### **Long Answer**

Official doc states

> Whether your application's processes should be created with a large
>   Dalvik heap. This applies to all processes created for the
>   application. 
> It only applies to the first application loaded into a
>   process; if you're using a shared user ID to allow multiple
>   applications to use a process, they all must use this option
>   consistently or they will have unpredictable results. 
> **Most apps should
>   not need this and should instead focus on reducing their overall
>   memory usage for improved performance**. Enabling this also does not
>   guarantee a fixed increase in available memory, because some devices
>   are constrained by their total available memory.

Some developers uses it to avoid OOM excepetion, so if you are using it just to avoid some **OOM** it is a very very bad pactice.

> **Never request a large heap simply because you've run out of memory and
>   you need a quick fix**. You should use it only when you know exactly
>   where all your memory is being allocated and why it must be retained

**If you actually need more space it's ok to use it**, you can use  [`getMemoryClass()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass()) to check the heap and [`getLargeMemoryClass()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getLargeMemoryClass()) large heap.

But if you can avoid using the largeHeap it would be the best way to go, as the official documentation continues:

> Yet, even when you're confident your app can justify the large heap,
>   **you should avoid requesting it to whatever extent possible**. Using the
>   extra memory will increasingly be to the detriment of the overall user
>   experience because garbage collection will take longer and system
>   performance may be slower when task switching or performing other
>   common operations. 
>  Additionally, **the large heap size is not the
>   same on all devices and may be exactly the same as the regular heap
>   size**. So even if you do request the large heap size, you should call
>   getMemoryClass() to check the regular heap size and strive to always
>   stay below that limit.

I also suggest you to have a look here **[Managing Your App's Memory](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html)**

Answer (score 7):

Personally I would say it doesn't really fall into the category of either 'good/bad practice' when used **correctly**.

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html):

> Most apps should not need this and should instead focus on reducing
>   their overall memory usage for improved performance. Enabling this
>   also does not guarantee a fixed increase in available memory, because
>   some devices are constrained by their total available memory.

If you have done **everything** in your power to reduce memory usage, and still require it, then it isn't a bad thing to use it.

If your app is hanging, you will need to directly address that - the `largeHeap` isn't a magic wand that will make problems go away for all devices. This point is made clear from the following extract of the Android Training docs:

> [The] ability to request a large heap is intended only for a
>   small set of apps that can justify the need to consume more RAM (such
>   as a large photo editing app). **Never** request a large heap simply
>   because you've run out of memory and you need a quick fix—you should
>   use it only when you know exactly where all your memory is being
>   allocated and why it must be retained. - [(source)](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html)

I should also add that Google will **not** reject your app for using it.