# Is there an alternative to android:largeHeap="true"

Tags: android, performance

I work with a lot of bitmaps, which far exceeds the maximum capability of

```
android: largeHeap = "true"
```

this method is obsolete, and I think will soon be closed, because it has a large number of security holes.

Now I want to find out whether there is an alternative to this command?

Write any ideas maybe your post will push me to new thought to solve this problem.

Comment: "this method is obsolete, and I think will soon be closed, because it has a large number of security holes" -- feel free to cite evidence of this. "Now I want to find out whether there is an alternative to this command?" -- work with fewer bitmaps, or smaller bitmaps, or bitmaps with lower bit depth.

Comment: The alternative is like Mr Murphy points out : "smaller bitmaps, or bitmaps with lower bit depth".

Comment: I've also just checked the docs and there's no thing such as `deprecated` or warning

Comment: You should never have used that to begin with.  Use LRUCaches and lazy loading techniques to minimize the number of images in memory.  Using that flag pretty much meant you were half assing your job.

Comment: How so? And if for example an application just needs a lot of good pictures! I don't want to sacrifice quality!

Comment: @GabeSechan "You should never have used that to begin with" is as stupid statement as saying that largeHeap has security issues. Depends on what kind of application you deal with. But in any case one has to learn how to properly handle images.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar It's prefered to optimize your app first before using larger heap. Enabling this also does not guarantee a fixed increase in available memory. So Gabe is right saying that first optimize and then request larger heap if you really need it

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar No, it isn't.  The number of applications that actually need that flag, rather than just being poorly implemented, is a fraction of a percent.  The odds that his is one is low.  The odds that his is one given that he actually asked this question are even lower.  Unless he shows a reason that he specifically needs it for his app, he should be discouraged from using it

Comment: @GabeSechan I agree that not all applications need largeHeap flag. But you don't know whether OP has such application or not. Blank statements like "don't use that" without full explanation on why are confusing for less experienced developers.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar If he's an inexperienced developer he definitely shouldn't be using that flag.  For them its ESPECIALLY important to be told not to use it, to ensure they don't pick up bad habits.  Telling an inexperienced dev that it may be ok to use would be more confusing, and its then even less likely to be the correct answer (since they're less likely to know how to do things the right way).  I'd view any mentor/teacher/senior dev who even mentioned that flag to an inexperienced dev to be incompetent at his job.

Comment: @GabeSechan and what if that inexperienced developer's app is exactly the one that needs that flag. He would be pulling his hair off to solve issue that is maybe non-existent. You have to provide full explanation or none at all. Just as I would not just say use largeHeap without further explanations, I would not say don't use it without explanation either.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar AN inexperienced dev should be taught to do things the right way, not to put in hacks.  Imagine if everyone took so little care-  your phone would be almost useless.  Your attitude is highly unprofessional.

Comment: @GabeSechan Did I ever said otherwise. I said you have to provide full information so that person can learn all ins and outs. If you give only half information that is close to useless. largeHeap is not a hack though it has been mostly abused as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Is using largeheap in Android manifest a good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480007/is-using-largeheap-in-android-manifest-a-good-practice/30480239#30480239)

That being said I've just checked the docs and there's no thing such as `deprecated` label or warning.

If your app makes hevy usage of memory, and you don't want to request a larger heap from `Dalvik` optimize your app.

Quote from @[Gabe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1631193/gabe-sechan)

> Use LRUCaches and lazy loading techniques to minimize the number of
>   images in memory.

Checkout also [**this official reference**](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html).

Comment: I think if you work with bitmaps, you should always enable that flag, because on some devices (Xiaomi comes to mind) there can be random OOMs without it even using image loader libraries.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Well actually the flag is there to be used when you think it's necessary :)!

Comment: @Sid Thank you! I'm sorry now that I can't lift you reputation:(

Comment: @SEd why not? you can :)

Comment: @Sid You're naughty! ;)

Comment: @Sid this maybe out of context, but dang you're cute

Comment: @Sid I will hold you to it, btw I am using a messenger app, would you suggest android: largeheap = " true" is a good idea for a messenger app? thoughts?

Comment: @MarissaNicholas I've started a new chat, let's discuss about this there in order to avoid too much comments here

Comment: I joined the chat now, but you were gone :(

Comment: @MarissaNicholas check it out now ;)

Answer (score 0):

I deleted

```
dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

from build.gradle to avoid having java OutOfMemoryError and to avoid

`android: largeHeap = "true"`

Comment: `dexOptions` is a compile-time flag, not application runtime.